# Chrome location permission with navigator.geolocation in React

Tags: reactjs

I use navigator.geolocation to get my latitude and longitude in React. The function operate well in localhost, but when I change into another url such as "http://10.211.55.3:3000",the IP of my parallel , Chrome doesn't ask me the permission and just block it. And I find **chrome://settings/content/location**. It's not adjustable, so I cannot change the permission into "allowed".

Like the information below.

[the picture of //settings/content/location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdCOg.png)

I want to make the permission be allowed.

Answer (score -1):

add domain 'http://10.211.55.3:3000' to address and enable ,relaunch chrome:

chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

And enjoy